# jQuery/AJAX data loading & replacement in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have this kind of chart in a dashboard-sort-of page (there's going to be a few more but let's keep this to the simplest one for now). 
(this is derived from HC documentation).

https://jsfiddle.net/_dario/ako8wg0c/16

so first I define a config object for Highcharts with a null series; separating the config from the data seems a logical way to proceed, because I plan to replace the data (and redraw the charts) along the way with more AJAX calls.

```
var config = {
  chart: {
    height:150,
    type: 'bar'
},
title: {
    text: null
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Sources']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Posts'
  }
},
legend: {
    enabled:false
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
  }
},
series: null
};
```

then I load my data with AJAX with a POST request to a backend script, add the series data to the config object and finally create a new Highcharts chart

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'ajax/loadmydata.php',
    data:window.query_vars,
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(d){
        console.log(d.platform);
        config.series = d.platform;
        var sourcesChart = new Highcharts.chart('sources-chart', config);
    }
});
```

The raw output from the AJAX call is something like this (formatted for clarity)

```
{
  "platform": [
    {
      "name": "Instagram",
      "data": 14133
    },
    {
      "name": "Twitter",
      "data": 4312
    },
    {
      "name": "Facebook",
      "data": 3685
    },
    {
      "name": "Blog",
      "data": 482
    },
    {
      "name": "Forums",
      "data": 671
    },
    {
      "name": "News",
      "data": 545
    }
  ]
}
```

but, when testing this lot, Highchart leaves an almost-empty chart, with the axes drawn but no data. With the console, I can confirm that the config object indeed contains the series data; 
any clue? Am I missing something in the data format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your JSON and the JSON in the fiddle you linked, there is one main difference. **Your data values are not wrapped in brackets**. `Highcharts.series.data` is an array, and therefore it needs to be wrapped in brackets, even if it is just one number.

Changing your JSON to this, means it works:

```
{
  "platform": [
    {
      "name": "Instagram",
      "data": [14133]
    },
    {
      "name": "Twitter",
      "data": [4312]
    },
    {
      "name": "Facebook",
      "data": [3685]
    },
    {
      "name": "Blog",
      "data": [482]
    },
    {
      "name": "Forums",
      "data": [671]
    },
    {
      "name": "News",
      "data": [545]
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
var config = {
  chart: {
    height:150,
    type: 'bar'
},
title: {
    text: null
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Sources']
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Posts'
  }
},
legend: {
    enabled:false
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
  }
},
series: []
};

d = {
  "platform": [
    {
      "name": "Instagram",
      "data": [14133]
    },
    {
      "name": "Twitter",
      "data": [4312]
    },
    {
      "name": "Facebook",
      "data": [3685]
    },
    {
      "name": "Blog",
      "data": [482]
    },
    {
      "name": "Forums",
      "data": [671]
    },
    {
      "name": "News",
      "data": [545]
    }
  ]
}

config.series = d.platform;
var sourcesChart = new Highcharts.chart('sources-chart', config);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="sources-chart"></div>
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/8ckxe2qw/

Comment: I have a question on [highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239291/6854117) can you please see it?